# Download PDFs under a specific header on webpage through Selenium Python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

How to download only PDF documents under the '**Design Review**' header from the below URL through Selenium in Python.

**`https://platform.sustain-cert.com/public-project/2756`**

Design Review header can be anywhere on the web page (top, middle or at bottom). There can be many unique headers apart from the design review header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you may try:

```py
import time
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

driver = Chrome()

url = "https://platform.sustain-cert.com/public-project/2756"
driver.get(url)

files = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.MuiBox-root.css-16uqhx7')))
print(f"total files: {len(files)}")

container = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.MuiContainer-root.MuiContainer-maxWidthLg.css-got2s4')))
categories = container.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div>h6')

for category in categories:

    if category.text == "Design Review":
        design_files = category.find_element(By.XPATH, "parent::*").find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.MuiBox-root.css-16uqhx7')
        print(f"total files under Design Review:: {len(design_files)}")

        delay = 5
        for file in design_files:
            file_detail = file.text.split('\n')

            if file_detail[0].endswith('.pdf)'):
                print(f"pdf files under Design Review:")
                print(file_detail[0].replace('(', '').replace(')', ''))
                # click button to download the pdf file
                file.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'button').click()
                time.sleep(delay)

            delay += 10
```

output:

```
total files: 12
total files under Design Review:: 6
pdf files under Design Review:
03 Deviation Request Form-Zengjiang wind power project-20220209-V01.pdf
pdf files under Design Review:
20220901_GS4GG VAL FVR_Yunxiao Wind_clean.pdf
```

Few things to note:

1. As you are only interested in the pdf files in the `Design Review` section, so we first locate the element using `h6` tag
2. next, we iterate over all `h6` tags and pick only the one with the `Design Review` text.
3. Then, we refer back to the parent element/tag of the filtered `h6` tag, find all the files, and store them in a variable `design_files`.
4. Now, we get all the files under the `Design Review` and we easily filter out the files which end with `.pdf`
5. finally, click on the located pdf file to download.

Downloading the files takes a bit of time, so we add incremental delay to wait for the current files to get downloaded before starting the next file download.

I hope this answers your problem.

Comment: I tried and am able to download  all the pdfs already  using XPATH. But  I need to download only those PDFs which are under header "Design Review".

each URL will be having 100's of PDF but am inetrested in only Design Review ones .

eg: https://platform.sustain-cert.com/public-project/2513

Comment: I've updated the answer, now it only downloads the pdf files under the 'Design Review'